# Sklearn StratifiedShuffleSplit with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a training and testing set from a pandas dataframe. When I run:

```
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(df['event'], n_iter=3, test_size=0.2)
```

I get the error:

`ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of labels for any class cannot be less than 2.`

However this is not the case because when I run:

```
df.event.value_counts()
```

I get:

```
irrelevant    5030
event         394
```

Any idea what could cause this issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce your warning. Out of curiosity, what is `len(df)`?

Comment: 5424. I just tried with a completely different csv and it works fine, im not sure what it is about this df that is causing the problem.

Comment: Looks like a blank line in the CSV was causing it

Comment: How did the blank line cause it?

Comment: I am not completely sure, I was looking at the CSV in excel and saw one row was empty so I deleted it and everything worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention in a comment to your question, it was the empty row/line that was causing the error.

The reason that `df['event'].value_counts()` didn't show the empty line is because [`pandas.Series.value_count()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) takes an optional parameter `dropna=True`; this parameter ignores all null/NaN/`np.nan`/`None` values by default. Here's a quick example to show this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])

In [4]: df['a'] = ['so', 'map', 'map', 'lol', np.nan, 'so', 'so', 'so', 'lol', np.nan]

In [5]: df['a'].value_counts()
Out[5]: 
so     4
lol    2
map    2
dtype: int64

In [6]: df['a'].value_counts(dropna=False)
Out[6]: 
so     4
lol    2
map    2
NaN    2
dtype: int64
```

In the output to line `6` you can see that `NaN` comes up as another class although by default (output to line `5`) it's not there. If you'd passed in this optional parameter as `False` you would've picked up on the null row in advance.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: This is great, will be helpful in the future.